# "An unknown error occurred." when changing profile avatar image

Tags: users

I'm trying to change my profile avatar image, and I'm getting a "An unknown error occurred." No indication of what might have gone wrong. Permissions are correct on `/craft/storage/userphotos` and all the user directories inside. What am I doing wrong?

Error message in `/craft/storage/runtime/logs/craft.log`:

```
2014/09/13 13:39:02 [warning] [application] 404 - 
2014/09/13 13:39:02 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /abs/path/to/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, this sounds like a bug. Go ahead and contact support@buildwithcraft.com directly (if you haven't already), and we'll close this question. Seeing as how this question is a month old, you've probably already resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the log files in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` and search for `[error]` or `[warning]` to see the underlying error message.

Comment: Added the error message to the question, doesn't appear to be related?

Comment: I think those may be old errors. Is there a way to clear the logs so I can try the action again?

Comment: Yeah... just delete that logs folder and it will be re-created.

Comment: I've got 8,200 lines, and at each iteration, the warning/error is above.

Comment: Is there any [error] or [warning] *not* related to a 404? You're looking for something related to when you were uploading your profile image.